# trouble getting into trusty environment after install

Tags: 14.04

After successful install ubuntu on samsung arm with command 'sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t xiwi'   can't start into environment, commands like 'startxfce' or similar did not work. after 'enter-chroot' shows '(trusty)myname@localhost:~$'
   Please advise, what i should do to get into desktop environment. Thank you!

ps/ sorry i am very new to linux

Comment: Have you tried the command `sudo startxfce4` to get into your desktop environment?

Comment: yes, that brought 'command not found'

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't installed any desktop environment for Ubuntu, so when you start Crouton it starts only the X.Org X Window System instead of the Xfce desktop environment. When you installed Crouton, the correct command to use to install both X.Org, which you need, and the Xfce desktop environment is:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t xiwi,xfce
```

The `-e` option `If not interactive, exit immediately if any untested command fails.` that you used before is optional in the above command.

The command to get into your desktop environment after it has been installed is:

```
sudo startxfce4
```

Comment: ok, may i just add some which is missing now?

Comment: sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce     will this do? thank you

Comment: I don't know, better to reinstall.

Comment: thank you for your help! this 'sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t xfce -u'   eventualy brought desktop to me.